# quote generator why ternary operator return undefined at last index?

Tags: javascript

i want to show quote from 0 to quote length but after the last index ternary operator return undefined value and then start from 0. How i can do that in other way?

```js
let quote = ["Celebrate Your Small Wins", "Surround Yourself With Motivated People", "Whatever you are, be a good one", "People who wonder if the glass is half empty or full miss the point. The glass is refillable.", "I’m alive, motivated and ready to slay the day"];

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var content = document.getElementById("content");

var i = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  i = i < quote.length ? ++i : 0;

  content.innerHTML = quote[i];
});
```

```html
<h2 id="content">Quote Will diplay here</h2>

<button id="btn">New Quote</button>
```

Comment: Just check the value of `i` after `i = i < quote.length ? ...` and you should find the problem in your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the quote at a position that is equal to `quote.length`.

Imagine your array has only one quote. `quote.length` will return 1. As soon as you press the button you will get `undefined` result.

```
var i = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // quote.length == 1
  // i = 0 and is less than 1
  // ++i will return 1 (max index is 0)
  i = i < quote.length ? ++i : 0;

  content.innerHTML = quote[i];
});
```

Update your logic to `i = i < quote.length - 1 ? ++i : 0;`.

There is one more problem you have: the first quote in the array is always skipped (never shown).

To fix that you need to switch the order of two lines:

```js
let quote = ["Celebrate Your Small Wins", "Surround Yourself With Motivated People", "Whatever you are, be a good one", "People who wonder if the glass is half empty or full miss the point. The glass is refillable.", "I’m alive, motivated and ready to slay the day"];

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

var content = document.getElementById("content");

var i = 0;
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Display the quote
  content.innerHTML = quote[i];
  // Prepare to shown the next quote
  // Notice quote.length - 1. We must not get value that is equal to `quote.length`
  i = i < quote.length - 1 ? ++i : 0;
});
```

```html
<h2 id="content">Quote Will diplay here</h2>

<button id="btn">New Quote</button>
```

Comment: `Update your logic to...` - Or just place the original line _after_ `content.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: I am feeling excited that I got a reply from stackoverflow community.I really appreciate your help.

This logic also working perfectly. 

i = i < 4  ? ++i : 0;

Because array has 5 values. Condition i < 5 is true it become 6 with increment And 6 index is undefined. So it was returning undefined output.

 This is my first code. Everyone building random quote machine so i decide  to build quote machine which return value from 0 to 10. After this exercise, I am feeling motivated and excited. I am sorry for my bad English, it's not my first language.

Thanks again

Comment: @Adnan, if you find an answer helpful and it fixes your problem the best gratitude you can show to stack overflow community is to accept the answer and optionally upvote it. Glad you have figured out how to fix the issue yourself!